# how to impose a condition after sorting an array list based on an order

Tags: java, arrays, list, algorithm, logic

lets say I have a array list:

```
List<Class1> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(new Class1("name1", "2"));
.
.
.
```

then I used the compare method to return my list in an order sorted by the name field.

```
name1:2
name1:1
name1:2
name1:3
name1:3
name2:2
name2:3
name2:1
name3:1
name3:2
name3:3
```

now Im trying to return a list containing the name values who have 1,2,3 in order?

now I want the expected output to be like:

```
name1 has the items 1,2,3 in order so its a problem.
name3 has the item 1,2,3 in order so its a problem.
```

how can I achieve this?

First I did sort my array list in order to achieve the above sorted list:

any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: An `ArrayList` of what? Are those `Strings`? Please create a [mre].

Comment: What is the result you are trying to achieve? Sorted by name and sorted by item value?

Comment: the result that I am trying to achieve is `name1 has the items 1,2,3 in order so its a problem.
name3 has the item 1,2,3 in order so its a problem.` and I thought probably sorting might Help.

Comment: are you looking for a list of names that contain 1,2,3 in order?
like [name1, name2] ?

Comment: yes thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the list of names that have 1,2,3 sequence.

```
List<Integer> subList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

//groupBy names
Map<String, List<Class1>> groupedByName = class1List.stream()
                .collect(Collectors
                        .groupingBy(
                                Class1::getName,
                                LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()
));
//filter out the names that contains sublist in the values
List<String> result = groupedByName.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> 
Collections.indexOfSubList(entry.getValue().stream().map(Class1::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList()), gg) != -1)
                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

first, the list is grouped by name and added to a linkedHashMap which keeps the insertion order. then a list of names containing the subList in the value array is returned.

Collections.indexOfSubList returns the subArray if present or returns -1 when a sub-array cant be found.
then the map is filtered with the only entries containing the sub-array. then the keys of the map are returned